# (103) Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed

Tags: tomcat, java, apache-2.4

The following errors are being logged in our proxy Apache logs while processing the request with Tomcat Server:

```
(103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed  
proxy: pass request body failed
```

We've a Apache reverse proxy which serves the request for the client from our Tomcat Server. Sometimes, the request from the proxy returns 502 with the above error.
There are no error logs in Tomcat Server Logs correlated with the above errors in Proxy. Also, the request didn't timeout since some of the requests response time is 1 sec and our default timeout is 120 sec.

We've added ProxyBadHeader Ignore to our httpd configuration [Ref: 502 Proxy Error / Uploading from Apache (mod_proxy) to Tomcat 7] and still didn't see any errors in our Tomcat logs.

Have anyone seen this issue earlier?

Comment: Try add `disableUploadTimeout="false"` in the tomcat connector.

Comment: This is not due to timeout, since the requests are getting terminated in milliseconds (i.e. < 0 Sec )

Comment: This error occurs if you set your backend server  connection timeout to be less than the timeout of your proxy keep alive connection. To solve the issue, either disable the reuse of connections if you don't need connection reuse or reduce your proxy ttl to be less than backend connection timeout

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same error recently. Our solution was to add:

```
SSLProxyProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

This matches our `SSLProtocol` parameter in our ssl.conf file. We also had Tomcat setup to disable SSLv3 as well.